# Dynamically assign value to a Property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, markdown, razor-pages

I have hard time understanding assigning value to a property dynamically, means during run time so that i can retrieve/display value in a razor page. I have following programming logic to accomplish my task, however this (LmitedWords) property does not render or hold any value to be displayed. How do I assign a value to this property during run time.

```
public class Post 
{

   public string Content { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public string LimitedWords { get; set; } 

 }
```

My controller code follow:-

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllPosts()
        {
            var myLimitProperty = new Post();
            var result = await _repository.GetAllPosts();

            foreach (var post in result)
            {
                var limitContent = ContentExtension.ReturnLimitedDescription(post.Content, size);               
                myLimitProperty.LimitedWords = limitContent; 

            }
            return View(result);
        }
```

my contentextension helper method returns value as expected and during debug it does show that local variable "limitContent" has the value but it somehow does not assign it to LimitedWords property, which is a property in Post class.

In my Post class there are other properties as well and i want them to be displayed as it is saved in the database.

My Razor page does not display content as it is null:

```
<div>
 <markdown markdown="@Model.LimitedWords">                    
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well based on what you have posted, the `result` holds the posts returned by the repository.

You loop through these posts, update the `myLimitProperty` local variable in the action and return the original collection.

Nothing is actually being updated on objects being sent to the view

Create a projection from the list, populating the desired properties that should be displayed in the view.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllPosts() {
    var posts = await _repository.GetAllPosts();

    var result = posts.Select(post => {
        var limitContent = ContentExtension.ReturnLimitedDescription(post.Content, size);
        var model = new Post() {
            Content = post.Content;
            LimitedWords = limitContent; 
        };
        return model;
    }).ToList();

    return View(result);
}
```